# Reference Base URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with a plugin that autogenerates a page in Wordpress.
The "Event" plugin creates a new page with slug "events".  The page is not registered in the "list of pages".

I need to add the events page to the main menu.

My problem is when I go to the appearances->menu, there is no element in the list of pages to add to the menu.  The only way to add the item is to manually create the link in the "custom link".

If I'm going to do this, is there any way to parameterize the baseurl?  for example:  instead of using link `"HTTP://homepage.com/events"`, I'm looking for `"{{ base URL }}/events"`

Is this possible?  if so, how?
Thank you

Comment: Is the plugin adding a page or a custom post type? There is no reason a "page" called "Events" would not appear in the list of pages. My guess is in the list of content to add to the menu (on the left side) there is a box called Events, and if you click "view all" there will be an option for All Events - that's what you add to your menu. If you don't see that, click on Screen Options at the top of the menu edit screen and you will probably see Events unchecked.

Comment: No dice.  tried: pages, posts, categories, woocommerce. clicked "view all", it's not there. but HTTP://<<homepage.com>>/events does exist.

Comment: What plugin are you using for Events?

Comment: woocommerce event manager.  I also have the pro add-ons.

Comment: Go to Appearance -> Menus and click Screen Options at the top and see if there is a checkbox for Events or Event Manager. If there is an it's unchecked, check it and then you should be able to add the events page to your menu.

Comment: ok.  found the options you stated.  Thank you for that.  Under Events, it says no items.

Comment: Is there a "View All" tab? Or create a single event and then that option should appear.

Comment: no.  no "View All" in any of the event categories.

Comment: what the page shows is a search and list engine for the plugin....ie. shows all the events to register for.

Comment: There should be more than categories, just a simple Events.

Comment: the problem is that this page is not a specific event.  it's the list of all events page.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the All Events link should do. It should be the Events Archive listing.

Comment: and there we are.  I can't find an All Events link in the rosters.  which is why I'm asking about the custom link.

Comment: Since I don't have access to your site, I would strongly recommend reaching out to the plugin support team, especially if you have pro add-ons.

Comment: Yeah.  that's a good idea.  I'm doing a hard URL for now until they get back to me.  Thanks!